# How to update gps coordinate every second in android?

Tags: android, gps

I am new to android development and this is my first application. My application is to track one phone using another application. I have now manage to do the first application which sends the gps coordinate. Now i am doing the second application and so far the application can retrieve GPS coordinate from mysql server and show it on the google map. The problem is my mysql database gets updated every second and i am having trouble refreshing my gps coordinate in my application. I tried using

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // call JSON methods here
            new JsonReadTask ().execute();
        }
    }, 60000  );
```

to call my Async Task but the application just crashed with an error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process
```

I have been searching and because of my lack of understanding in android i am finding it very hard to change and implement solution to solve my problem. Can anyone please help me.

my activity code

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {



private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://address.com/recieve1.php";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
    accessWebService();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        jsonvalue();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
}



public void jsonvalue() {
    List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("my_coor");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String latitude = jsonChildNode.optString("latitude");
            String longitude = jsonChildNode.optString("longitude");
            String coordinates[] = {latitude, longitude};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Creating GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
            mapView = fragment.getMap();

            LatLng location;
            location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
            mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
            mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }






    }
```

The complete error log

```
04-22 20:50:25.236  11023-11023/com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker E/Zygote﹕     MountEmulatedStorage()
04-22 20:50:25.236  11023-11023/com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker E/Zygote﹕ v2
04-22 20:50:25.236  11023-11023/com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG]   get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-22 20:51:34.331  11023-12546/com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker, PID: 11023
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing   doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at   com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker.UNMCtoTTSActivity$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(UNMCtoT     TSActivity.java:66)
        at com.unmcbus.unmcbustracker.UNMCtoTTSActivity$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(UNMCtoTTSActivity.java:61)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you are executing the task the array in doInBackground will be empty because you are not passing an URL.

Of what I can see, this should pass the URL:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // call JSON methods here
        accessWebService();
    }
}, 60000  );
```

Comment: When i use this code it is showing error for .accessWebService as Cannot Resolve Method. Is there other method which i can use to refresh the coordinate and show new location in my code? Thank you Chris.

Comment: sorry, i must have misread your code. does it work if you simply call accessWebService(); istead of new JsonReadTask().accessWebService(); ?

Comment: your very welcome. i updated the original answer to match the working code

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete Error Log for clear understanding of the error.

However I am able to find a problem in your code
--> You cannot do any UI operation from a background thread (`doInBackground()` method)

Comment: I have posted the complete Error Log.
when i run the application without the "new Handler().post Runnable()", it runs well without error and show the gps location on map. I added the "new Handler().post Runnable()" to make the application to get the gps coordinate frequently. Is there any other way or method which i can use in my code to refresh the gps coordinate and show in my map?
thank you Ankit.

Comment: Well, from the handler you are passing "null" as parameter for `doInBackground()` and accessing `params[0]` which is creating the error. And, if you are fetching coordinates from your own server.. try running a background SERVICE which do this task ------ if you can use LocationServices to fetch coordinates then there is a method `registerLocationUpdates()` in it which can work for you.